# Error establishing a database connection in Google Cloud Platform Wordpress site

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress, database-connection

Since 14.2. my site is giving this error:
Error establishing a database connection

I have a Wordpress site at Google Cloud Platform ID  XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
I have not changed anything for several months, everything has been fine until now.
How to fix this. Is there a way to register a support issue with GCP?

Answer (score 1):

I replaced your domain name and platform id because this is a public forum and it's required to avoid sharing private information about your project. Please next time keep in mind that.

I am part of the support team, but for your case it's better to [create a support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures#create_a_support_case) because we need to get more information to troubleshoot the issue.

We need to know which product are you using exactly, please check this [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/wordpress). Or you are just using your self-hosted Wordpress on a Virtual Machine?

You can find a similar issue in the following Google Groups [forum](https://groups.google.com/g/gce-discussion/c/7W0KX9Wxk_I).
I suspect that having your webserver unmanaged for a few months can lead to a memory related issue. So best thing you could do is to ssh into the machine, check database logs (*/var/log/mysql/*) and check database service status `$ sudo systemctl status mysqld.service`.

Comment: It seem mysql is not running and and does not start from the comman line:

Comment: tkoskine@wordpress-multisite-1-vm:/opt/bitnami$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start mysql
/opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql  could not be started
Monitored mysql
tkoskine@wordpress-multisite-1-vm:/opt/bitnami$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
php-fpm already running
apache already running
mysql not running

Comment: Please check `$ sudo systemctl status mysql.service` and logs in _/var/log/mysql/error.log_ or similar.

Comment: my /var/log directory listing looks like this: Which files should I check?
apt
auth.log
btmp
debug
dpkg.log
gonit.log
kern.log
messages
ntpstats
syslog
unattended-upgrades
user.log
wtmp